Will placing bare hands on floor while sanding cause fingerprints to appear in stain
My wife and I are refinishing the oak hardwood floors on the second story of our home.  We are just getting to the end of all the sanding, and are now thinking about how we want to finish the floors.  We have decided to stain them darker to match the rest of the woodwork in the house.  Her father says that years ago, they refinished their floors, they wore just their socks throughout the process, and when they put their finish down, they ended up with a lot of footprints in their finished floor.  As I think back to our sanding process, we wore clean indoor-only shoes, but we did come into contact with the floors with our bare hands throughout the process.  We obviously want to avoid a repeat of what happened with her parents.  Could touching the floors with bare hands cause hand and fingerprints to appear once the floor is finished?  If so, how can we prevent this?  Or is it possible that something else caused the imperfections her parents experienced that we don't need to worry about?  And is it the oils from our skin that would cause it, or dust and debris if we do not clean the floors properly prior to refinishing?

Oil from skin can hold onto dust/dirt more, so good cleaning is essential.  Most socks/shoes will leave dust/hairs behind collected from other floors, so you do not want to walk from other rooms without putting on plastic booties or similar.

understood, thanks for the advice... so you don't think it is the hand/skin oil itself then?

It does not help.  Applying paint or stain, you want a very clean surface.  Painting/staining is the easy part of the job.  The prep before painting/staining is the hard/longest part for a good job.  If laying hands on the surface, maybe try latex gloves.

I see, we will be sure to get the floor as clean as possible before proceeding.  Thank you!
